# Determine layers in wms address angularjs

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I am using angularjs and I want to enter a wms address and check what are the available layers that I could select. Ive tried http.Capabilities but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sample below. This might help you.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="WMSCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="num in nums">{{num}}</li>
    {{data}}
    <button ng-click="get_data()">Get stuff</button>
</ul>
```

```
function WMSCtrl($scope, $http) {
$scope.nums = [1,2,3]
$scope.data = null;
$scope.get_data = function() {
  var url2 = 'http://giswebservices.massgis.state.ma.us/geoserver/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&SRS=EPSG:26986&BBOX=11830.0,776202.9449152543,348201.0,961492.0550847457&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=390&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript&FEATURE_COUNT=10&QUERY_LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&X=120&Y=109&FORMAT&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS'
  $http.jsonp(url2, {params : {REQUEST: 'GetFeatureInfo'}});
}

window.parseResponse = function(data) {
  $scope.data = data
}
}
```

Plunker given below [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jCUSh/145/)

Comment: it would be like ill input a wms base url and it will return list of layers.

Comment: Above is a sample which you can modify the way you need.

Comment: coz ive tried to modify the url like http://wms.geo.admin.ch/ its not showing anything